# How do I compile only certain modules with '-auto' cost centers?

Tags: haskell, profiling, ghc

I am profiling a program using ghc's option `-fprof` option to automatically create cost centers.  The profiling output would be easier to understand if I only had cost centers from particular modules.

Compiling everything first as `ghc --make main.hs -rtsopts -prof` and then recompiling some modules as `ghc -c SomeMod.hs -rtsopts -prof -fprof-auto` seemed like the right solution to me.

From the [GHC manual](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/prof-compiler-options.html) on the `-fprof` options:

> These do not have to be used consistently for all modules in a program.

But if you do this then the recompilation checker will detect that 'flags have changed' once you try to compile `main.hs` again.  I also tried `ghc --make main.o` thinking that I should start from the object file created in either of the earlier steps, but that didn't link successfully.

I happened to discover that putting a `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fprof-auto #-}` pragma in the appropriate modules achieves the intended goal.  Is that really the only way to do it though?

Answer (score 4):

Using `OPTIONS_GHC` (as you discovered) is how I would do it. I can't think of any other ways assuming you use cabal.